# crossdomain.xml received but still in violation

Tags: flash, socket.io

In flash I put:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
socket = new FlashSocket("http://engine.WEBSITE1.com:8002");
```

when I run the flash file online it then automatically asks my node.js app through port 8002 for the **/crossdomain.xml**, so I added this code before socket.io connects:

```
app.get('/*',function(req,res,next){
 if(req.method==='GET'&&req.headers.referer.indexOf('http://WEBSITE0.com/')===0&&req.url==='/crossdomain.xml'){
    console.log('/crossdomain.xml');
    flash=true;
    var body='<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="WEBSITE0.com" to-ports="8002"/></cross-domain-policy>';
    console.log(body);
    res.writeHead({'Content-Type':'text/x-cross-domain-policy'});
    res.write(body);
    res.end();
    }
  else if(req.method==='GET'){console.log('???');console.dir(req);}
  });
```

[image]

I see that I get the cross domain policy but still get denied with security sand box violation. **In fact the violation is not what i expected at all, as flash is asking for the cross domain policy then refusing to load data from there even though ALSO I have an identical (appart from website names) crossdomain.xml on both websites**

```
<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="WEBSITENAME" to-ports="*"/></cross-domain-policy>
```

[image]

My swf file then fails to receive the FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT event even though; in my node.js app I put this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  if(flash===true){console.log('flash');}
```

I do see the console say **"flash"**! just adobe is saying no to me... any thoughts?